# Conditional reference declaration in template class

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, alias

In a template class, how to define a property alias conditionally to the template?

Example:

```
template<class Type, unsigned int Dimensions>
class SpaceVector
{
public:
    std::array<Type, Dimensions> value;
    Type &x = value[0]; // only if Dimensions >0
    Type &y = value[1]; // only if Dimensions >1
    Type &z = value[2]; // only if Dimensions >2
};
```

Is this conditional declaration possible? if yes, how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Specialise* the first two cases:

```
template<class Type>
class SpaceVector<Type, 1>
{
public:
    std::array<Type, 1> value; // Perhaps no need for the array
    Type &x = value[0];
};

template<class Type>
class SpaceVector<Type, 2>
{
public:
    std::array<Type, 2> value;
    Type &x = value[0];
    Type &y = value[1];
};
```

If you have a common base class then you gain a measured amount of polymorphism for common functionality.

Comment: Might also want a `static_assert` in the primary template to ensure that `Dimensions` is valid.

Comment: Nice, however, why not have the specializations derive from each other?

Comment: @songyuanyao: changed it, although the way I had it compiled (perhaps in error) in MSVC2013.

Comment: What about making the reverse specialization? deleting the reference if dimension is less than k?

Comment: @TartanLlama Thanks, but I don't see why not (it's very possible I'm not following your logic through). Perhaps I'll try it for myself and see further.

Comment: @AdrianMaire: That sounds rather posh. Why not submit an answer?

Comment: @Bathsheba: I am not sure, just trying now. Your specialization with little variants seem the way in any case.

Answer (score 2):

If you can do without the array, you could do this:

```
template<class Type, std::size_t Dimension>
class SpaceVector
{
public:
    Type x;
};

template<class Type>
class SpaceVector<Type, 2> : public SpaceVector<Type,1>
{
public:
    Type y;
};

template<class Type>
class SpaceVector<Type, 3> : public SpaceVector<Type,2>
{
public:
    Type z;
};
```

This is more scalable if you decide to support more than three elements, but otherwise, Bathsheba's answer is probably more suitable.